# Имитация нажатия клавиш Android

Tags: java, android

Имитация нажатия клавиш Android

Как сделать так чтобы в Сервисе с имитировать нажатие клавиш 1 и 2.

Хочу в программе телефон с имитировать нажатие 1 и 2

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотите. Что за "клавиши 1 и 2"? Это цифры на QWERTY клаве, кнопки в вашей активити или попытка набора номера стандартной звонилкой? Может вам просто нужно кинуть ссыль на способы коммуникации сервиса и активити?..

Comment: без рута нельзя отправить события нажатия чужому приложению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

возможно вам нужно это

```
public static void simulateKey(final int KeyCode) {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception when sendKeyDownUpSync", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

список всех кнопок (KeyCode) можете [найти тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)