# SmartTV+телефон. Нужен совет

Tags: android

Есть телефон, есть Smart с андроидом. Появилась следующая задумка: Сделать клиент-сервер т.к телевизор и телефон в одной сети то можно будет без проблем подключиться. Так вот, реально ли сделать так, что бы набирая текст на клавиатуре телефона (Или сделать свою клавиатуру в приложении?) отправлять на клавиатуру телевизора? Может ли клавиатура телека принимать интенты? Или как генерировать нажатия клавиш? В общем реально ли такое сделать? Реализуемо ли вообще в принципе? Спасибо за советы.

Comment: [возможно вам нужно это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478362/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-android)

Comment: Спасибо. И видел тему, но т.к она закрыта до конца не листал. Если правильно понял то с помощью sendPointerSync(MotionEvent event)  можно эмулировать перемешение мыши?